# How can I change the publishing rate of a node when the node is running?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a publisher and subscriber with a constant publishing rate. I want to change (increase or decrease) the publishing rate while the node is running ? I want to know if it is possible ?
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239431/how-can-i-change-the-publishing-rate-of-a-node-when-the-node-is-running?/) by [TAIMAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27479/taimaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is, if you have access to the source code for your node, you can make it do whatever you want.

Most users use [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) for changing parameters at run time. If you create a dynamic_reconfigure parameter for your publishing rate, you can use the dynamic reconfigure gui to change it while the node is running.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TAIMAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27479/taimaz/) on 2016-07-18**:
thank you, it was very useful.